# How to modify standard commands in PHP

Tags: php, replace, command, standards

Is it possible to modify standard commands in PHP? I would like to use ' **{{** ', for instance, instead of ' **echo** '.

In my practice I use ' **echo "** ' and ' **";** ' very often, to print whole string. For example:

```
echo "
<div class='someClass'>
  <table id='someTable'>
    <tr>
      <td> Hello </td>
      <td> World </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
";
```

As for me it's much more convenient and the code looks more readable then ever when use ' **echo** ' for every new line. But is it possible to make it look more pretty, like in Laravel Framework, for example.

```
{{
<div class='someClass'>
  <table id='someTable'>
    <tr>
      <td> Hello </td>
      <td> World </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
}}
```

I tried to **difine** a constant:

```
define ('{{', 'echo "');
define ('}}', '";');
```

But this did not work. As well as replacing all code using **str_replace** in one variable with needed symbols and then print it.

```
$a = str_replace('{{', 'echo "', $someVariableWithAllCodeAsText);
$a = str_replace('}}', '";', $someVariableWithAllCodeAsText);
```

So the question is: **is it possible in general**?

Comment: Why bother, its a four character instruction. And what happens when somebody else gets the job of maintaining your code. They wont have a clue whats going on

Comment: Even if it were possible, I would strongly discourage you from doing this, it will make your code virtually impossible to understand for anyone but you, and if you require you to rewrite the entire thing if you needed to post it anywhere.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Well, I'm just curious if it is possible and how this function implemented in different frameworks.

Comment: Can you point us at some documentation where `{{` and `}}` are used in Laravel or whereever

Comment: The only way I see this is possible is to write your own parser. Though, its an interesting question! I don't get, why people just downvote it. Sure, it's kind of crazy to change things like `echo` for no reason, but it's interesting to know if this is possible or not. So the question is good, as long as no one gets the idea to really do that! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function :

```
function _($html)
{
    echo $html;
}
```

Then just use in your code :

```
_('<h1>Hello World !</h1>');
```

You can also use :

```
<?= '<h1>Hello Worlds !' <?>
```

For a shorter way.

But in general, you won't be able to do this, you can see all templates engines like Smarty or Twig, they parse template code to replace `{{` by `echo`

Answer (score 0):

There are some legitimate ways of making defined text 'prettier', but not exactly how you are intending.

Firstly, you can define blocks of HTML in an HTML file and just use an [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) statement to insert the block. However, this isn't good for dynamic content.

Secondly, you can use [`heredoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax to define strings. This will allow the use of variables.

Thirdly, you don't have to include all content you are outputting in PHP, even if it is dynamic. Checkout [escaping from HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) on the PHP documentation site. Here is an example from there:

```
<?php if ($expression == true): ?>
    This will show if the expression is true.
<?php else: ?>
    Otherwise this will show.
<?php endif; ?>
```